# Bootstrap: Removing click event on custom checkbox's label

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

Good day,

```
<div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1"><label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">Default checkbox</label></div>
```

How to i remove the click event on the checkbox's label of bootstrap?

currently, by default, to change the input:checkbox state you either click the box or the label of the checkbox...

but what i want is, i only want them to click the box to change the state.. clicking the label wont change the state.

thanks you in advance.

Comment: try to remove for="defaultCheck1" on label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
change from `for="defaultCheck1"` to `for="defaultCheck2"`
```

try this

```
<div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck2"><label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">Default checkbox</label></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `<label>` element outside the `<div class="form-check">` element. I think the click event is actually on that div.